# Dynamical array of strings in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make array of strings, I have function `rLine` which reads line from stdin, each inputted line I need to save in array, but I don't have any idea about number of inputted string lines. So I need to dynamically increase array size to store them, I wrote such code:

```
char *res[2], *old = res;
while( 1 ){
  line = rLine( stdin ), len = strlen( line );
  res[row] = (char*)malloc( len + 1);
  strcpy( res[row++], line);
  res = (char**) realloc( res, row ); /* adding 1 more row, not sure adding size row? */
  if ( /*some cond*/ ) break;
}
```

But this code doesn't seem to work, how correctly declare array and increase it size?

Comment: Why dont you implement a simple linked list and store a string within each element?

Comment: The problem is that res is not a pointer to pointer, is an array of pointers, with 2 elements preallocated.

Comment: How do you distinguish EOF?  Couldn't `rLine()` tell you the length of the string?  Why cram two assignments onto one line?  (Using a comma operator works, but it isn't necessary here and should not be used unless it is necessary.)

Comment: `rLine` reads input until '\n', but I can't add it to whole string only unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, an array of pointers is different than a pointer to pointer. You can't try to assign allocated memory to an array.

You should declare `res` as a pointer to pointer and allocate memory at the beginning of the loop before using it.

Try it out like this:

```
char **res = NULL, *old = res;
while( 1 ){
  line = rLine( stdin ), len = strlen( line );
  res = (char**) realloc( res, sizeof(char**) * (row + 1) ); /* adding 1 more row, not sure adding size row? */
  res[row] = (char*)malloc( len + 1);
  strcpy( res[row++], line);
  if ( /*some cond*/ ) break;
}
```

Remember that arrays decay to pointers in most situations but are handled very differently underneath.

Comment: There are two minor issues here.  (1) Allocating one line pointer at a time like that can become expensive; it is usually better to keep track of the number of lines allocated separately from the number used, and to double the number of lines allocated each time you `realloc()`.  (2) You have a leak if the `realloc()` fails because it just wrote a NULL over the only pointer to the allocated memory.  You should never use `data = realloc(data, size)`; use `void *new_data = realloc(old_data, new_size);` and test the value of `new_data` before copying it over `old_data`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, totally agree with both points (I usually use a step size instead of doubling realloc though) but for the sake of simplicity and to keep the code similar to the old one, I just did minor changes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agree also, just for simplicity, but I added `*old = res` then error handler `if ( res == NULL )` and then assigning old to beginning

Comment: Fair comment, though it's never too early to instill good practices into those learning to program.  There'll come a point at which they don't ask questions, even though they probably should.  The doubling is better than a linear increment, IIRC, but a 'bigger than 1' increment is better than the increment by 1.  If you're worried about the over-allocation, you can always do a shrinking `realloc()` when you're done with the loop, setting the array to the correct size.  That won't move the data, either.